# Google AdSense Policy Non Compliant "Site Behaviour: Navigation"

Tags: google-adsense-policies

I am having a dilemma with Google AdSense over at my blog. It seems the violation is in respect to one specific page.

**The violation is**: Site Behavior: Navigation
Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:

> False claims of downloadable or streaming content Linking to content
>   that does not exist Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading
>   webpages Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model
>   of the website.

A common mistake for this violation is broken links on the page. I have fixed all of those. Any request for further specifics from Google is futile.

Anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: might have something to do that half the videos are about guns/violence  (no matter under what topic you place them), Google just doesn't like that.

Comment: There are square images at the top on the left and the right.  They are half off my screen and all link to `/subscribe/`.   That looks really wonky

Comment: Thanks man, this actually fixed my https issue. I have a violation on the page for the http non-SSL side too. After a review, the https violation went away but the http version is still there. Weird since I have redirect on...

Answer (score 4):

Google considers that you're responsible for the content displayed on your site... period. Therefore it's possible that your 3rd party ads are breaking the terms and conditions of the Adsense program.

Currently, your website appears to use an excessive amount of ads but more important some of their ads are low quality, misleading and even promote installing of potential unwanted items.

***Example 1:***

The below ad is misleading because it implies it will play an embedded YouTube video when it, in fact, it redirects you to a shady 'sales' site.

[image: Fake Youtube Video]]

***Example 2:***

Other ads link to unfavourable websites that scream spam, and in a lot of Antiviruses can be even blocked.

[image: Nod32 unwanted software]]

I highly recommend that you use only reputable advertising networks!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, they were clickbank ads but I understand that they can be spammy. I have since deleted them from the site.